# How to configure Kubernetes to encrypt the traffic between nodes, and pods?

Tags: kubernetes

In preparation for HIPAA compliance, we are transitioning our Kubernetes cluster  to use secure endpoints across the fleet (between all pods). Since the cluster is composed of about 8-10 services currently using HTTP connections, it would be super useful to have this taken care of by Kubernetes.

The specific attack vector we'd like to address with this is packet sniffing between nodes (physical servers).

This question breaks down into two parts:

- Does Kubernetes encrypts the traffic between pods & nodes by default?
- If not, is there a way to configure it such?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually the correct answer is "it depends". I would split the cluster into 2 separate networks.

1. **Control Plane Network**

   This network is that of the physical network or the underlay network in other words.

   k8s control-plane elements - kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, kube-proxy, kubelet - talk to each other in various ways. Except for a few endpoints (eg. metrics), it is possible to configure encryption on all endpoints.

   If you're also pentesting, then [kubelet authn/authz](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authorization) should be switched on too. Otherwise, the encryption doesn't prevent unauthorized access to the kubelet. This endpoint (at port 10250) can be hijacked with ease.
2. **Cluster Network**

   The cluster network is the one used by the Pods, which is also referred to as the overlay network. Encryption is left to the 3rd-party overlay plugin to implement, failing which, the app has to implement.

   The Weave overlay [supports encryption](https://github.com/weaveworks-experiments/weave-kube/issues/38). The service mesh linkerd that @lukas-eichler suggested can also achieve this, but on a different networking layer.

Comment: as Eugine mentioned, the Weave supports encryption as network overlay but it comes with great cost of network performance: https://itnext.io/benchmark-results-of-kubernetes-network-plugins-cni-over-10gbit-s-network-36475925a560

Answer (score 9):

The replies here seem to be outdated. As of 2021-04-28 at least the following components seem to be able to provide an encrypted networking layer to Kubernetes:

- Istio
- Weave
- linkerd
- cilium
- Calico (via Wireguard)

(the list above was gained via consultation of the respective projects home pages)

Answer (score 6):

> Does Kubernetes encrypts the traffic between pods & nodes by default?

Kubernetes does not encrypt any traffic.

There are servicemeshes like [linkerd](https://linkerd.io/) that allow you to easily introduce https communication between your http service.

You would run a instance of the service mesh on each node and all services would talk to the service mesh. The communication inside the service mesh would be encrypted.

Example:

your service -http-> localhost to servicemesh node - https-> remoteNode -http-> localhost to remote service.

When you run the service mesh node in the same pod as your service the localhost communication would run on a private virtual network device that no other pod can access.

Comment: I would like to add [Istio](https://istio.io) as another example for a service mesh which brings https communication to your existing http services.

Comment: @PasanW.note that istio doesn't support headless services (and thus - stateful sets) with mtls enabled

Answer (score 1):

No, kubernetes does not encrypt traffic by default

I haven't personally tried it, but the description on the [Calico software defined network](https://www.projectcalico.org/) seems oriented toward what you are describing, with the additional benefit of already being [kubernetes friendly](http://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.4/getting-started/kubernetes/)

I thought that Calico did native encryption, but based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/projectcalico/felix/issues/997) it seems they recommend using a solution like IPSEC to encrypt just like you would a traditional host